# In azure Devops, Run on unit Test on Multi-Agent, how to collect the code coverage file and Publish into Artifact

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, code-coverage, sonarcloud

In azure Devops, Run Unit Test(VSTest) on Multi-Agent, how to collect the code coverage file and Publish into Artifact. In pipeline show only test result .trx File and unable to view .coverage File.

YAML Template File:

```
# Unit Test Execution      
- job: UnitTests_Execution
  displayName : 'Unit Tests execution'
  dependsOn: 'UnitTest_Build'
  condition: and(succeeded(), ${{ and(eq(parameters.RunCondition, 'True'), eq(parameters.RunUnitTest, 'True')) }})

  variables:
    BuildPlatform: 'any cpu'
    BuildConfiguration: 'release'
  
  pool:    
    name: 'Self-Hosted Agent'
  strategy:
    parallel: 8
      
  steps:
    - checkout: none
    
    - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
      displayName: 'Download Build Artifacts'
      inputs:
        artifactName: unitTests
        targetPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/unitTests'
    
    - task: VSTest@2
      displayName: 'Unit Tests'
      inputs:
        testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
        testAssemblyVer2: |
          **\*test*.dll
          !**\*TestAdapter.dll
          !**\obj\**
        searchFolder: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/unitTests'
        resultsFolder: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\TestResults\'
        runOnlyImpactedTests: false
        vsTestVersion: '${{ parameters.VsVersion }}'
        # runInParallel: true
        codeCoverageEnabled: true
        testRunTitle: 'Unit Testing service layer'
        platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
        rerunFailedTests: true

    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1 
      displayName: 'Publish Artifact: Code Coverage'
      inputs:
        targetPath: '$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/TestResults'
        artifact: CodeCoverageResult
```

Using Multi-Agent, Am tried to collect the code covearge File and Merge into single File and publish into Sonar Cloud Dashboard

Excepted: In pipeline log only show the Test result .trx File and not show .coverage File. But in Single Agent it was working am excepting to work on multi-Agent concept.

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the same issue when using the multiple-agents jobs.

[image]

It seems that the Code Coverage option doesn't support in vstest task when using multiple-agents jobs.

The Pipeline runs will point to the same Test Run link and not execute the real test method.

To solve this issue, you can use the [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) to loop the jobs to run the multiple jobs.

Here is an example:

```
parameters:
- name: runtimes
  type: object
  default: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]


jobs:
- ${{ each runtime in parameters.runtimes }}:

  - job: UnitTests_Execution_${{ runtime }}
    displayName : 'Unit Tests execution ${{ runtime }}'
    dependsOn: 'UnitTest_Build'
    condition: and(succeeded(), ${{ and(eq(parameters.RunCondition, 'True'), eq(parameters.RunUnitTest, 'True')) }})

    variables:
      BuildPlatform: 'any cpu'
      BuildConfiguration: 'release'
    
    pool:    
      name: 'Self-Hosted Agent'

        
    steps:
      - checkout: none
      
      - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
        displayName: 'Download Build Artifacts'
        inputs:
          artifactName: unitTests
          targetPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/unitTests'
      
      - task: VSTest@2
        displayName: 'Unit Tests'
        inputs:
          testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
          testAssemblyVer2: |
            **\*test*.dll
            !**\*TestAdapter.dll
            !**\obj\**
          searchFolder: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/unitTests'
          resultsFolder: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\TestResults\'
          runOnlyImpactedTests: false
          vsTestVersion: '${{ parameters.VsVersion }}'
          # runInParallel: true
          codeCoverageEnabled: true
          testRunTitle: 'Unit Testing service layer'
          platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
          configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
          rerunFailedTests: true

      - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1 
        displayName: 'Publish Artifact: Code Coverage'
        inputs:
          targetPath: '$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/TestResults'
          artifact: CodeCoverageResult
```

In this case, it will run 8 parallel jobs too. And it can show the expected behavior.

Here is the result: .trx file and .coverage file

[image]